# How to perform Kneser-Ney smoothing in NLTK at word-level for tri-gram language model?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, pytorch, trigram

I am trying to train a tri-gram language model on a text corpus and want to perform KN smoothing. Apparently, the 'nltk.trigrams' does this at character-level. I was wondering how I would be able to do this at word-level and also perform KN smoothing. Here is a piece of code that I wrote and doesn't work:

```
    with open('file.txt',"r",encoding = "ISO-8859-1") as ff:
        text = ff.read()

    word_tok = tknzr.tokenize(text)
    ngrams = nltk.trigrams(word_tok)
    freq_dist = nltk.FreqDist(ngrams)
    kneser_ney = nltk.KneserNeyProbDist(freq_dist)
    print(kneser_ney.prob('you go to'))
```

I get the error:

```
    Expected an iterable with 3 members.
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line:

```
print(kneser_ney.prob('you go to'))
```

with:

```
print(kneser_ney.prob('you go to'.split()))
```

Then it works ok. I get a value of 0.05217391304347826 when using a as training file the text from the novel "Moby Dick" downloaded from Project Gutenberg

With this modification, your code becomes analogous to thefollwing:

```
with open('./txts/mobyDick.txt') as ff:
    text = ff.read()


from nltk import word_tokenize,trigrams
from nltk import FreqDist, KneserNeyProbDist


word_tok = word_tokenize(text)
ngrams = trigrams(word_tok)
freq_dist = FreqDist(ngrams)
kneser_ney = KneserNeyProbDist(freq_dist)
print(kneser_ney.prob('you go to'.split()))
```

Also everything here is being done a the word level and not at the character level:

```
ngrams = trigrams(word_tok)
for _ in range(0,10):
    print(next(ngrams))

#('\ufeff', 'The', 'Project')
#('The', 'Project', 'Gutenberg')
#('Project', 'Gutenberg', 'EBook')
#('Gutenberg', 'EBook', 'of')
#('EBook', 'of', 'Moby')
#('of', 'Moby', 'Dick')
#('Moby', 'Dick', ';')
#('Dick', ';', 'or')
#(';', 'or', 'The')
#('or', 'The', 'Whale')
```

The frequency distribution is also at word level:

```
freq_dist.freq(tuple('on the ocean'.split()))
#7.710783916846906e-06
freq_dist.freq(tuple('new Intel CPU'.split()))
#0.0
```